# Find each table whose first cell has one of two words followed by three digits

Tags: vba, ms-word, wildcard

I would like to fix the following code to make it find each table in the document where it has the pattern `ARC` or `MEC` words followed by the wildcard digits `[1-4][1-9]{2}` without any leading/trailing characters, digits, spaces, etc.

The chosen table should have a total of 11 rows.

If possible, I need another version of the code to search for the pattern in the table first cell `.Cell(1,1)` while making sure the table has a total of 11 rows.

```
Sub FindTables()
    
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document, t As Long
    Set wdDoc = ThisDocument
    
    With wdDoc
        
        For t = 1 To .Tables.Count
            
            With .Tables(t).Range.Find

                .ClearFormatting
                .Format = FALSE
                .Text = "(ARC)|(MEC)[1-4][1-9]{2}"
                .Forward = TRUE
                .Wrap = wdFindStop
                .MatchCase = TRUE
                .MatchWildcards = TRUE
                .Execute
                
                If .Found = TRUE Then
                    ' some operations on the table
                    wdDoc.Tables(t).AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
                    wdDoc.Tables(t).Range.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                End If
                
            End With
            
        Next
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Format = False
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Text = "<[ACEMR]{3}[1-4][1-9]{2}>"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute = True
   If .Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
    If .Tables(1).Rows.Count = 11 Then
      'If .Cells(1).RowIndex = 1 And .Cells(1).ColumnIndex = 1 Then
        If Split(.Cells(1).Range.Text, vbCr)(0) = .Text Then
          Select Case Left(.Text, 3)
            Case "ARC", "MEC":  .Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
          End Select
        End If
      'End If
    End If
    .Start = .Tables(1).Range.End
   End If
   .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

To process only those tables where the found content is in the first cell, delete the tick marks from the two comment-out lines.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; if you don't mind I have some questions to better understand your approach: 1- why do your prefer `.Wrap = wdFindContinue` to `wdFindStop`? 2- Is there a special character in `"[ACEMR]{3}[1-4][1-9]{2}"` to indicate that the search pattern shouldn't be preceded or followed by any character/digit/space? 3- Can't we write something like `ARC|MEC` instead of picking three characters out of the pool `[ACEMR]`?

Comment: If you were to use wdFindContinue, Word would just loop endlessly. There is no special character in the Find expression - once could precede it with < and follow it with > to make sure there are no alphanumeric characters before or after found string, bit that seems pointless - the If test with Split function checks whether what's in the cell (or at least the cell's first paragraph) is nothing more than what was found. Word's *wildcard* function doesn't allow the specification of alternate strings

Comment: "_If you were to use wdFindContinue, Word would just loop endlessly._" so, do you mean that you intentionally make Word endlessly loop over all the tables? If yes, how to prevent it from finding the already found/processed tables?

Comment: My bad. Code updated.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration. BTW, is my approach right in the question by using the property _.Found_ instead of _Do While .Find.Execute = True_? I don't understand how _.Execute_ works, so I rely on _.Found_ :)

Comment: One can use either. My current preference is for *Do While .Find.Execute*, but I've also posted many examples using *Do While .Find.Found* and *Do While .Found*. The biggest difference, though, is that you relied on an If test (which stops at the first instance) whereas I used a Do While loop to process all instances.

Answer (score 1):

Pattern:

```
"(ARC[1-4][1-9]{2})|(MEC[1-4][1-9]{2})"
```

Tested successfully with Microsoft VbScript Regular Expressions 5.5. (set this Reference on VBE).

Code sample - adapt it to suit your needs (working with tables - I didn't reproduce your scenario):

```
Function fnFindPatterns()
    Dim objRegExp As RegExp
    Dim ObjMatch As Match
    Dim colMatches As MatchCollection
    Dim strText As String
    Dim strResult As String

    Set objRegExp = New RegExp
    objRegExp.Pattern = "(ARC[1-4][1-9]{2})|(MEC[1-4][1-9]{2})"
    objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
    objRegExp.Global = True

    Selection.WholeStory
    strText = Selection.Text

    If objRegExp.Test(strText) = True Then 'we have something there...
        Set colMatches = objRegExp.Execute(strText)
        For Each ObjMatch In colMatches  'Iterate on the collection
            strResult = strResult & ObjMatch.Value & vbCrLf
        Next
    Else
    End If

    MsgBox strResult

End Function
```

Edited 2022 07 11:

I realized that the "|" (OR) do not work in MSWord . It doesn't exist on the limited "Regular Expressions" set of tools within MsWord, compared to VbScript.RegExp. Wich, in turn, is also limited set of tools, if compared with other (powerfull) programming languages. But with some coding we "simulate" this OR, using "Choose", testing each partial set of patterns that way:

```
Sub FindTables()
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document, t As Long, intChoose As Integer
    Set wdDoc = ThisDocument
    
    With wdDoc
        For intChoose = 1 To 2
            For t = 1 To .Tables.Count
                With .Tables(t).Range.Find
                    .ClearFormatting
                    .Format = False
                    .Text = VBA.Choose(intChoose, "<[ARC]{3}[1-4][1-9]{2}>", "<(MEC)[1-4][1-9]{2}>")
                    .Forward = True
                    .Wrap = wdFindStop
                    .MatchCase = True
                    .MatchWildcards = True
                    .Execute
                
                    If .Found = True Then
                        ' some operations on the table
                        wdDoc.Tables(t).AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
                        wdDoc.Tables(t).Range.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                    End If
                    
                End With
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

To test this code I mounted a Word Doc with 7 tables (varying dimensions from 1 x 11 to 1 x 13). To ensure the correct dimension of each table insert the suggestion posted in Macropod's code.

Comment: Seems like a lot of code and RegEx overhead to not even do half the job...

Comment: Well, this is what we have to do while programming in Excel VBA. This is not a working solution. As requested by Diaa, this is another way to (begin) working with a NEW code.

Comment: But this is for *Word*, not Excel, and Diaa didn't even mention Excel in this thread - Excel isn't even tagged.

Comment: Diaa: "...I need another version of the code to search for the pattern..." The VBE and its ActiveX are available for all components of the MS 365 package. With the necessary adaptations, it will run in Word, Excel, Outlook, etc. And, in the case of ActiveX VBScript.RegEx, it can (and should) be used, if it solves the problem.

Comment: And the code I posted is for MsWord. Check out. 'Excel' came up only as a comment.